# How can I start the JFileChooser in the Details view?

Tags: java, windows, swing, jfilechooser

I would like my JFileChooser to start in details view, instead of the "List" view that it starts in.  How do you do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get the Action from the ActionMap:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JFileChooser  fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
Action details = fileChooser.getActionMap().get("viewTypeDetails");
details.actionPerformed(null);
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
```

Comment: Nice, that's probably a better way to do it.  Actually, maybe you can help me with my problem over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229526/how-do-you-remove-the-ctrlc-action-on-a-jfilechooser#comment23321430_16285866

Comment: is this still the solution in 2021? or is there a better or other way how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a little tricky and probably not officially supported, but I found out how to do this.  First, you need to get the FilePane that the JFileChooser has.  The only way I know how to do that is to traverse its components and then do an `instanceof FilePane` until you get it.  Then this will start in Details view:

```
    if (root instanceof FilePane) {
        FilePane filePane = (FilePane) root;
        Action viewTypeAction = filePane.getViewTypeAction(FilePane.VIEWTYPE_DETAILS);
        viewTypeAction.actionPerformed(null);
    }
```