How to open a JFileChooser with the file sort being last modified?
I want to open a JFileChooser with the sorting option being set to modified descending by default.
Anyone have any ideas?
(I'm relatively new to swing)
Cheers
I've found this older solution but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

What have you done/tried?   Welcome. Take the [tour] and then see how to [ask].

The more recent answer to the question linked to is 2 1/2 months old.  Does the code in that answer not work?

Update to original suggestion works for me in JDK11 on Windows.

There appears to be a duplicate post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429779/start-a-jfilechooser-with-files-ordered-by-date check this out and let me/us know if this answers your question, and I'll mark your question as duplicate?

Turns out it (the older solution) works but creates a second window, I'm going to play around with it and see if I can get it to only open one window. Thanks guys.
