# Save the state of a JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

A user has asked that I preserve the state of the JFileChooser across application restarts. Specifically, he has asked that I preserve the state of the Details / List view type selection. Two applicable questions:

[How can I start the JFileChooser in the Details view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292502/how-can-i-start-the-jfilechooser-in-the-details-view)

[Start a JFileChooser with files ordered by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429779/start-a-jfilechooser-with-files-ordered-by-date)

These both show methods of starting the JFileChooser with specific default behavior. The piece that is missing is a way to determine what behavior the user had active (view type, sort order) when the JFileChooser window is closed, so that it can be saved and restored later. Any ideas?

Comment: It is `Serializable`. You can serialize and deserialize it on demand. (Though I have never tried it.)

Comment: Thanks. I just tried serialize / deserialize, based on your recommendation. The information that I am interested in is not contained in the serialized data, and so this does not work as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on feedback, I have created the following class. I believe that this gives all the functionality I am looking for. This class depends on [this SwingUtils class](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/).

You will also need to update access restriction rules (at least in Eclipse) to allow access to `sun/swing/FilePane` as described in

[Access restriction: Is not accessible due to restriction on required library ..\jre\lib\rt.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266632/access-restriction-is-not-accessible-due-to-restriction-on-required-library/10642163#10642163)

### Edit: Cleanup resource leak

After coming back to work from a long vacation, I realized that the code I initially provided could leak `JFileChooser` instances, and so I have reworked it to provide an `AutoCloseable` entity that can be used in a **try-with-resources** statement. Sorry for the churn.

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import sun.swing.FilePane;
import darrylbu.util.SwingUtils;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class JFileChooserPersisterFactory {
    private static final String VIEW_TYPE_LIST = "viewTypeList"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String VIEW_TYPE_DETAILS = "viewTypeDetails"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String CHOOSER_CLOSING_PROPERTY = "JFileChooserDialogIsClosingProperty"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String VIEW_TYPE_PROPERTY = "viewType"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String IS_DETAILS = "isDetails"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String SORT_ORDER = "sortOrder"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private JFileChooserPersisterFactory() {
    }

    public static JFileChooserPersister createJFileChooserPersister() {
        JFileChooserPersisterImpl persister = new JFileChooserPersisterImpl();
        persister.init();
        return persister;
    }

    public interface JFileChooserPersister extends AutoCloseable {
        JFileChooser getJFileChooser();

        @Override
        void close();
    }

    private static class JFileChooserPersisterImpl implements JFileChooserPersister {
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
        private final Preferences persistentPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(getClass());

        private final JFileChooser chooser;
        private boolean isDetails;
        private OnChooserClosing chooserClosingListener;
        private FilePane filePane;
        private OnViewTypeChanged viewTypeChangedListener;

        public JFileChooserPersisterImpl() {
            chooser = new JFileChooser();
        }

        public void init() {
            restoreSettings();
            registerForViewTypeChangeEvents();
            chooserClosingListener = new OnChooserClosing();
            chooser.addPropertyChangeListener(CHOOSER_CLOSING_PROPERTY, chooserClosingListener);
        }

        @Override
        public JFileChooser getJFileChooser() {
            return chooser;
        }

        private void persistSettings() {
            persistentPrefs.putBoolean(IS_DETAILS, isDetails);
            if (isDetails) persistSortOrder();
        }

        private void persistSortOrder() {
            byte[] serializedSortOrder = serializeSortOrder();
            if (serializedSortOrder != null)
                persistentPrefs.putByteArray(SORT_ORDER, serializedSortOrder);
        }

        private byte[] serializeSortOrder() {
            List<? extends SortKey> keys = getRowSorter().getSortKeys();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream)) {
                out.writeObject(new SortOrderInfo(keys));
                return byteStream.toByteArray();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Could not serialize JFileChooser row sort order.", e); //$NON-NLS-1$
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void restoreSettings() {
            isDetails = persistentPrefs.getBoolean(IS_DETAILS, false);
            if (isDetails) {
                setToDetailsView();
                applyInitialSortOrder();
            } else {
                setToListView();
            }
        }

        private void setToDetailsView() {
            Action details = chooser.getActionMap().get(VIEW_TYPE_DETAILS);
            details.actionPerformed(null);
        }

        private void setToListView() {
            Action details = chooser.getActionMap().get(VIEW_TYPE_LIST);
            details.actionPerformed(null);
        }

        private void applyInitialSortOrder() {
            byte[] serializedSortOrder = persistentPrefs.getByteArray(SORT_ORDER, null);
            if (serializedSortOrder == null) return;
            ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedSortOrder);
            try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(byteStream)) {
                setSortInfo((SortOrderInfo) in.readObject());

            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                logger.error("Could not deserialize JFileChooser row sort order.", e); //$NON-NLS-1$
            }
        }

        private void setSortInfo(SortOrderInfo info) {
            info.setSortOrder(getRowSorter());
        }

        private RowSorter<?> getRowSorter() {
            JTable table = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JTable.class, chooser).get(0);
            RowSorter<?> rowSorter = table.getRowSorter();
            return rowSorter;
        }

        private void registerForViewTypeChangeEvents() {
            filePane = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(FilePane.class, chooser).get(0);
            viewTypeChangedListener = new OnViewTypeChanged();
            filePane.addPropertyChangeListener(VIEW_TYPE_PROPERTY, viewTypeChangedListener);
        }

        private final class OnChooserClosing implements PropertyChangeListener {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                persistSettings();
            }
        }

        private class OnViewTypeChanged implements PropertyChangeListener {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                isDetails = ((int) evt.getNewValue()) == FilePane.VIEWTYPE_DETAILS;
            }
        }

        public static class SortOrderInfo implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -5393878644049680645L;
            private final List<ColumnSortInfo> keyInfo = new ArrayList<>();

            public SortOrderInfo(List<? extends SortKey> keys) {
                for (SortKey sortKey : keys) {
                    keyInfo.add(new ColumnSortInfo(sortKey));
                }
            }

            public void setSortOrder(RowSorter<?> rowSorter) {
                rowSorter.setSortKeys(makeSortKeys());
            }

            private List<SortKey> makeSortKeys() {
                List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<>();
                for (ColumnSortInfo info : keyInfo) {
                    keys.add(info.makeSortKey());
                }
                return keys;
            }

            public static class ColumnSortInfo implements Serializable {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 5406885180955729893L;
                private final SortOrder sortOrder;
                private final int column;

                public ColumnSortInfo(SortKey sortKey) {
                    column = sortKey.getColumn();
                    sortOrder = sortKey.getSortOrder();
                }

                public SortKey makeSortKey() {
                    return new SortKey(column, sortOrder);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            chooser.removePropertyChangeListener(CHOOSER_CLOSING_PROPERTY, chooserClosingListener);
            filePane.removePropertyChangeListener(VIEW_TYPE_PROPERTY, viewTypeChangedListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+ SwingUtils can come in handy. I'm still surprised that the property change events generated by the FilePane class are not available to the JFileChooser class. We should not have to use a class like SwingUtils to access the events. Seems like a file chooser design bug.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Properties` API or `Preferences` API to save/restore user data.

1. At start up you would read the users data and set the file chooser property.
2. To listener for user changes to the view type you can add a `PropertyChangeListener` to the file chooser and listen for the `viewType` event. Then you would update the user data with the new value.

You can add a `RowSorterListener` to the `RowSorter` to listen for changes in the sort order. You would then need to save the sort order. I don't know the best way to store the sort data.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. If I add a `PropertyChangeListener` for "viewType" to the `JFileChooser`, it never fires when changing between List and Details. I tried adding a `PropertyChangeListener` without specifying the property to listen for, and several events fire when creating / showing the window, but while the window is open, no events are fired at all when changing the view type. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Okay. So I just figured out that I need to add the listener to the `FilePane`, not to the `JFileChooser`. I think it will work that way.

Comment: @danBhentschel - `I just figured out that I need to add the listener to the FilePane, not to the` - good to know. How do you access the `FilePane` of the file chooser?

Comment: I have added my implementation as an answer based on your suggestions and other information I have gleaned. Thank you for the help. Please feel free to point out anything stupid that I have done. The `FilePane` is part of the "restricted" non-API Swing code. Normally I would feel uncomfortable using this code, but in this case, the JVM is bundled with my application, so I am relatively protected from implementation variation.