# How can I let Metal give all option dialogs the same title bar color as JFrame's when using it's window decorations?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog

I use

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

to have windows use the window decorations of Metal.

Metal has a title bar color for different types of `JOptionPane`'s. Nice feature, but for this case it's annoying.

How can I let Metal give all option dialogs the same title bar color as `JFrame`'s?

Comment: DefaultLookAndFeelDecorated changed standard Native OS's decoration to AWT decorations for container, with JComponents in XxxLookAndFeel

Comment: @mKorbel Of course, that's the purpose of that method.

Comment: see answer by @kleopatra  [how is JOptionPane accesible, for any enjoy with...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18107432/714968)

Comment: I think that must be possible with Xxx.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(Xxx.XXX)

Comment: See *UIManager Defaults*, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16304588/230513).